# How to convert the text columns to libsvm format using feature hasher from scikit learn

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-engineering

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829531/making-an-input-text-file-as-a-training-data-set-in-libsvm) links to a code which only works for numeric data , but I have  CSV file for machine learning which has mostly text data and most columns have a large cardinality , eg: a column with name of a person.
Ideally would like to use the scikit learn's feature hasher or a vectorizer to generate the file in libsvm format hashing the text feature values to appropriate numeric values.

Note:

The graphlab ML library takes inputs with non numeric values in its Sframe and the Sframe is used in the classifiers like xgboost. So it is already doing what I require but it is not opensource and we dont get the numeric table output from the sframe. Most likely graphlab is using some feature hasher internally to keep track of the mappings between the text values and numeric values.
scikit already provides the feature hasher library which maps a value to appropriate numeric values.

So how to  convert the text columns to libsvm format using feature hasher from scikit learn , Also will this cause changes in the results of the classifier?

Comment: Probably irrelevant, but just in case you want libsvm format to train an SVM model, then there's no need for all that. You can train [SVMs using scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) directly.

Comment: @MarcClaesen I am using other libraries(xgboost)  which require input in libsvm form

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to represent your data as a dictionary.
   For example:

`measurements = [
{'city': 'Dubai', 'temperature': 33.},
{'city': 'London', 'temperature': 12.},
{'city': 'San Fransisco', 'temperature': 18.}
]`

2. Vectorize the categorical columns (encode categorical feature as K
   binary features).
   You can use [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.) or [FeatureHasher](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher.html). The latter is more memory efficient. For example, the above dictionary will be transformed to a sparse array:

`from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
vec = DictVectorizer()`

vec.fit_transform(measurements).toarray()
array([[  1.,   0.,   0.,  33.],
       [  0.,   1.,   0.,  12.],
       [  0.,   0.,   1.,  18.]])

3. Finally, save the sparse matrix as a SVMlight data format by sklearn's function [dump_svmlight_file](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.dump_svmlight_file.html)

**EDIT:**
To get the feature names:

```
feature_names = vec.get_feature_names()
print "Feature_names: " + str(feature_names)
```

Comment: It should preserve the Column names so that we can find feature importance

Comment: No problem at all. It returns `feature_names_`. You also have the method `get_feature_names()` - read here[link] (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html)

Comment: No this is possible only if the model is within scikit learn but if I use the data in other classifier systems then it is not possible.

Comment: I use DictVectorizer with models outside sklearn all the time. It has nothing to do with the model. It just gives you a list of features, where the index of the feature_name in the list is the index of the new corresponding binary column. See example for text here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/hashing_vs_dict_vectorizer.html